# How would I go about converting this recurrence relation to closed form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form, recursion, recursive-algorithms

So I looked at a part of code and came up with a recurrence relation for it and I got:
$$T(0) = 1,$$
$$T(n) = 3 + 2T(n-1).$$

Then I solved it using substitution and got:

$$T(n) = 2^i*T(n-i)+3(2^i-1).$$

I'm confused on the steps to convert this to closed form, any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Parentheses, please.  You mean $2^{i-1}$.  If you are going to write it inline, it should be 2^(i-1).  Better yet, see the FAQ for MathJax

Comment: no it's 2^i -1. the 1 isn't in the exponent sorry i'll look at MathJax

Comment: You are right, so you do have the parentheses you need.  I missed that it was the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a base case, likely $T(0)$ or $T(1)$.  You choose $i$ to make use of the one you get.  You can take $i=n-1$ and write $T(n)=2^{n-1}T(1)+3\cdot (2^{n-1}-1)$ if you have a value for $T(1)$.

Comment: I have T(0) = 1

Comment: Then you take $i=n$ and get $T(n)=2^nT(0)+3(2^n-1)=2^n+3(2^n-1)=2^{n+2}-3$